# TypeError: contact() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

[i was creating blog website using flask and flaskALacedemy and i got error please help me for this thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMQ3R.png)

i was creating blog website using flask and flaskALacedemy and i got error please help me for this thank you

```py
    from flask import Flask,render_template,request
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from datetime import datetime

    app=Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 
    'mysql://root:@localhost/myfirstweb'
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    class Contact(db.Model):
    serial_no = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    phone_no = db.Column(db.String(12), unique=False, nullable=False)
    message = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(12), unique=False, nullable=True)

    @app.route('/')
    def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

    @app.route('/about')
    def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

    @app.route('/contact', methods  = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def contact():
    if(request.method=='POST'):

        name = request.form.get('name')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        phone = request.form.get('phone')
        message = request.form.get('message')

        entry = 
     contact(name=name,email=email,phone_no=phone,date=datetime.now(), 
    message=message)
        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template('contact.html')

    @app.route('/post')
    def post():
    return render_template('post.html')

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: you should put your code or error here instead of image.

Comment: Please put the code alongside the image. If you really want to keep the image, make sure first that you have the code.

Comment: i got error Please refer my code

Comment: Your indentation is not correct. Could you edit your post to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `contact` doesn't expect any parameters and still you are still doing this: `contact(name=name,email=email,phone_no=phone,date=datetime.now(), message=message)`